# Put JSON object in Array after AJAX

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, object

I do an AJAX where I get a JSON object (questions) :

```
function questionnaire()
{
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/configuration/nacellesquestionnaire",
        success: function(questions)
        {
            displayQuest(questions);

            return questions;
        },
        error: function()
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

So , with the `return questions`, I want to put this JSON object in an Array :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var questBackup;
    questBackup = questionnaire();
});
```

The problem : When I check the array `questBackup` with a console.log(), there are an "undefined" ...

Note : when I do `console.log(question)` in success AJAX I have the correct JSON object.

Comment: AJAX here is not a synchronous call and you will not get the response of url request directly on method call. I would suggest you to read on ajax calls before you proceed further.

Comment: you are making asynch ajax call so before the questionnaire() method return's the object the calling function prints questBackup hence undefined. Instead call questionnaire() in document.ready and then call a function from success of ajax request to save data.

Comment: Thank for your comments ! I have solve the problem with a callback function.